# R: Keep same set of default colors in visNetwork, even when having missing groups

Tags: r, colors, visnetwork

I want to plot a network using the visNetwork package. I would like my nodes across all the different networks using the same colors for the same groups. So I want

- group A -> blue
- group B -> yellow
- group C -> red.

which are the first 3 default colors. Here is a first simple example:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, label = paste("Label", 1:10), 
                    group = factor(c("A","B","C", "A","C","C","C","A","A","A"), levels=c("A","B","C"))) 
visnw <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visLegend(position = "right")
visnw
```

This gives
[image]

But when I omit group B the color "red" disappears even when I specify that column 'group' is a factor containing 3 levels, this fact is ignored in the visualisation. Moreover, when the first element is not "A" this are shuffled even more.

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, label = paste("Label", 1:10), 
                    group = factor(c("C","A","C", "A","C","C","C","A","A","A"),c("A","B","C"))) %>%
                    dplyr::arrange(group) #needed to have A as first group but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the second visualisation
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,5,10), to = c(1,2,10))
visnw <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visLegend(position = "right")
visnw
```

However, the above code gives me this which is wrong because group C must have color red. Moreover the groups are switched because nodes 1,3,5,6,7 belong to group "C" and not "A". This latter problem doesn't ariwe when I omit the arrange(), but then the legend has level "C" on top and below level "A" which isn't nice.

[image]

I have tried to edit the list visnw, but this doesn't work.

I almost can achieve what I want by explicitly defining the colors I want for each group.

```
visnw <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "A", color = "lightblue") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "B", color = "yellow") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "C", color = "red") %>%
  visLegend(position = "right")
visnw
```

This gives me this visualisation:

[image]

I prefer to use the default colors, since I like them and there is also an edge on the node in the default scheme which I should have to define manually as well. Anybody knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The default group color options are provided by vis.js; you can see the full list [here](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/blob/4879d7caf2a02e34e7936dc3da2101d342a0b2ae/lib/network/modules/Groups.js#L13).

Based on the parameter list in the link above, you can, for example, fully replicate the default group styling for the first group like this:

```r
visnw <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  ## 0: blue
  visGroups(groupname = "A", color = list(border = "#2B7CE9", background = "#97C2FC", highlight = list(border = "#2B7CE9", background = "#D2E5FF"), hover = list(background = "#2B7CE9", border = "#D2E5FF")))
```

Alternatively, if you want to change just the salient parameters, you can try the following:

```r
visnw <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  ## 0: blue
  visGroups(groupname = "A", color = list(border = "#2B7CE9", background = "#97C2FC")) %>%
  ## 1: yellow
  visGroups(groupname = "B", color = list(border = "#FFA500", background = "#FFFF00")) %>%
  ## 2: red
  visGroups(groupname = "C", color = list(border = "#FA0A10", background = "#FB7E81")) %>%
  visLegend(position = "right")
visnw
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that if you want "A" "B" and "C" to be the first three default colors regardless of if and how they are used, you can do this first:

```
visnw.groups.get("A");
visnw.groups.get("B");
visnw.groups.get("C");
```

The default behavior of .get() is to create each group using the next available default.

Now it won't matter if you introduce nodes in a different order or have no nodes in group "B", as the groups have been created beforehand.

Comment: Hi Paul, I receive an error: `Error in visnw.groups.get("A") : 
  could not find function "visnw.groups.get"`